# React Router: State empty when navigating to route via the browser address bar

Tags: reactjs, react-router, use-state

I have created a Modal which is part of my Router configuration:

```
  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={appContextValue}>
      <ProductLanding getProductModalTemplate={getProductModalTemplate} />
      <Switch location={isModal ? previousLocation : location}>
        <Route path="/cart">
          <Cart />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/product/:id">
          <Modal
            modalTemplate={
              productModalTemplate != null ? productModalTemplate : null
            }
            isModal={isModal}
          />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
      {isModal ? (
        <Route exact path="/product/:id">
          <Modal
            modalTemplate={
              productModalTemplate != null ? productModalTemplate : null
            }
            isModal={isModal}
          />
        </Route>
      ) : null}
    </AppContext.Provider>
```

I noticed when navigating via the browser to get to the route `http://localhost:3001/product/3` the products array which is propagating Modal template is empty, so I added the following:

```
  if (!products.length) {
    console.log('products ', products);
     return null
  }
```

How can I fix this?

Any help would be appreciated!

**Update:**

I updated the `<Switch/>`

```
 <Switch location={isModal ? previousLocation : location}>
    <Route path="/cart">
      <Cart />
    </Route>
    <Route exact path="/product/:id">
      <Modal
        modalTemplate={
          productModalTemplate != null ? (
            productModalTemplate
          ) : (
            <div>Nothing</div>
          )
        }
        isModal={isModal}
      />
    </Route>
  </Switch>
```

So now when going to the route via the browser bar, the div `Nothing` gets rendered.

I know why! The way I have it the template is being propagated by the clicks in the ProductListing page:

```
  <div className={productClasses}>
        <LinkButton
          to={`/product/${id}`}
          onClick={() =>
            handleGetProductModalTemplate(<ProductModalTemplate />)
          }
        >
          <img className={styles.image} src={imageSrc} alt={title} />
        </LinkButton>
        <div className={styles.details}>
          <div className={styles.text}>
            <LinkButton
              to={`/product/${id}`}
              onClick={() =>
                handleGetProductModalTemplate(<ProductModalTemplate />)
              }
            >
              <h2 className={styles.title}>{title}</h2>{' '}
            </LinkButton>

            <span className={styles.price}>${finalPrice}</span>
          </div>
```

Nothing get rendered via the address bar because `handleGetProductModalTemplate` never fires!!! So my friends what would be the best way to handle this? I am sure the way would be **React-Router**. Like  if this route is hit do this...

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is due to exact parameter which you have passed in params of Route tag.

Comment: But isn't that what I should have? You mean `<Route exact path="/product/:id">
`

Comment: I removed it. `<Route path="/product/:id">` Didn't work. But thanks for your insight.

Comment: So, on console what you are getting ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post your implementation of `handleGetProductModalTemplate()`. The way I would approach this sitation in my applications is I would use the useHistory() hook from React-Router to trigger the route change.

I would suggest you remove the to={`/product/${id}`} prop from the `<LinkButton>` component and instead pass the id value to the `handleGetProductModalTemplate()` function.

Perform your required logic inside `handleGetProductModalTemplate()` and then at the end trigger the route change.

let history = useHistory()

inside the `handleGetProductModalTemplate()` at the very end have this

```
history.push(`/product/${id}`)
```

This way you can ensure that `handleGetProductModalTemplate()` is being called before triggering the route change